# JavaScript - Is it possible to modify the behaviour of setInterval/setTimeout used by third party scripts (externally hosted)

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I have a 3rd party tool that hosts their JavaScript on a CDN and I dont want to implement a custom version script due to the amount of changes, rapid development, they make. Part of their JavaScript executes a setInterval with a timer of 8 minutes.

I was wondering if it was possible to access the Timer stack and modify the 8 minutes to 100 seconds for all subsequent timer events?

If not, would a suggested alternative approach be to re-write/override the setInterval function with my own custom js and make sure my custom js loads first before all other js, and then modify the timeout with a matching if condition, if 8 minutes change to 100 seconds? My assumption would be something like this:

```
window.setInterval = function(callback, timeout) {
//check timeout for 8 minutes
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot modify it. You'd have to cancel it and schedule it again with a different time - or, as you've described, intercept the `setInterval` call right away.

Comment: I am not used to being this deep into the overall stack, and am not surprised that the browsers dont give api access to the Timer stack to view and/or modify the intervals on the Timer stack waiting for the timer to fire to then be dropped onto the task queue stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'd try to avoid this at all cost (except to try "for fun").

Here may be the result (a setInterval where all intervals >= 100 seconds are replaced by 100 seconds)

```
// above the use of setInterval by third party code
(function (w, maxVal) {
  var f = w.setInterval;
  w.setIntervalOld = f;
  w.setInterval = function () {
    var a = arguments;
    if(a.length >= 2 && (a[1] > maxVal)) {
      a[1] = maxVal;
    }
    f.apply(w, a);
  };
})(window, 100000);
```

I tried to make the hack in the most coherent way and window.setIntervalOld is available for your own code. Tell me what it does for you.

Comment: Thank you for this. Im going with your answer over dandavis because I am not in control of the function/callback/workflow originally being executed. With your solution, I am seeing the setInterval being called by 3rd party, along with multiple other calls, and see the a[1] changing where needed. I can see the disadvantages of this and will probably keep this in the 'for fun' bucket.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a self-dispatching setTimeout routing instead of using setInterval:

```
function workload(callback) {
 var timeout=5000; //default run time
  if(Math.random()>0.5){ timeout=1000; } // special run time (50/50 in this demo)
  setTimeout(workload, timeout);

  //do normal workload:
   console.log(callback, timeout);
} // end workload

// use any time for first run:
setTimeout(workload, 12345);
```

you can also use a "static property" to externally adjust the timer:

```
function workload(callback) {
  setTimeout(workload, workload.timeout || 5000); //default to 0.2hz

  //do normal workload:
   console.log(callback, workload.timeout);
} // end workload

// use any time for first run:
setTimeout(workload, 2000);

workload.timeout=1000; // change to poll at 1hz;
```

Note that I didn't actually implement the callback, and without bind() the argument will be empty each execution. because the function itself is basically the callback, you don't need one. You could easily turn one of these patterns into a factory where you pass it a workload function, a default interval, an initial delay, and another conditional evaluator function for ultimate flexibility.